# A light and accurate classifier which is doable on a device with limited sources

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification

I have a project which I should classify the data coming from several sensors(time series based data) like gyroscope to several classes. I have used several classifiers including SVM, decision tree, neural networks, KNN,... in a batch scenario. My ultimate goal is to find a real-time classifier which is accurate, light and also has the ability to improve itself to implement it on my device which has limited sources(CPU, RAM,..). I was thinking a semi-supervised classifier since I can save a few labeled data on my device and use the future data points to improve my classifier. Does anyone have any recommendation or experience in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Online learning is very challenging. I recommend you steer away from now and use batch learning. You can always update the model as you update the mobile app or just make the app look for a new updated model on your server every x days.

Now, how to run a machine learning algorithm efficiently on a phone with limited resources. First, you have to identify which platform you are using. I assume you want to get a platform agnostic answer. Most ML algorithms (except [lazy learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_learning) ones) can run efficiently on smartphone, have a look at this [benchmarking experiment](https://github.com/naitik0212/Benchmarking-Machine-Learning-on-mobile-CPU).

You have several options here:

1. iOS: [Here's a list](https://github.com/alexsosn/iOS_ML) of all machine learning libraries available publicly.
2. Android: [Weka for Android](https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android), this lib has a huge number of ML algorithms.
3. Platform agnostic deep learning: Tensorflow, you can export your models to [TensorFlow lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/) ([tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-on-mobile-tutorial-1-744703297267)) and deploy them on any mobile OS and [Caffe2](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2) to train deep learning models and export them to any smartphone OS.

Comment: Thank you for your information. However, in the batch scenario, since I don't have any ground truth scenario how I can update model?

Comment: Collect your data first. Train your model. Export and deploy. Repeat.

Comment: @messi if you find this answer helpful, please upvote it and select it as best answer :)

Comment: Here the problem is that our labeled data points are slender and in order to avoid concept drift we have to improve it. I am thinking about a model which be able to improve itself in the course of time may be a semi-supervised model.